# EXCEL. Função "Direita" como definir um tamanho automático para células distintas que ultrapasse a quantidade de caracteres definidos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Usei a função direita na célula "L33" mas quando eu fui clicar e arrastar os valores definidos na primeira célula, a célula "L34" exibiu não apenas a palavra 'tecnologias' e sim a metade da palavra 'software' e em seguida a palavra 'tecnologias'.

Como eu faço para exibir apenas a palavra 'tecnologias' na célula "L34"??

No caso eu queria clicar e arrastar sem precisar se preocupar com palavras que ultrapasse os tamanhos definidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A última palavra está sendo encontrada de maneira incorreta.

Duas formas que podem ser utilizadas para encontrar a última palavra:

- `=DIREITA(H1;NÚM.CARACT(H1)-PROCURAR(" ";H1))`

> O problema desta função, é que funciona somente para duas palavras, irá retornar tudo após o primeiro espaçamento.

- `=ARRUMAR(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(ARRUMAR(H1);" ";REPT(" ";100));100))`

> Já esta função retorna a última palavra.

A concatenação da `última palavra + " " + valor na coluna G` está sendo realizada da maneira correta:

`=CONCATENAR(ARRUMAR(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(ARRUMAR(H1);" ";REPT(" ";100));100));" ";G1)`

Comment: Eu só não consegui concatenar a numeração da "G33", tentei: =ARRUMAR(DIREITA(SUBSTITUIR(ARRUMAR(H33);" ";REPT(" ";100));100);CONCATENAR(ESQUERDA(H33;PROCURAR(" ";H33)-1);" ";G33)). Mas é obvio que não deu certo

Comment: Deu certo! só uma correção aí no "concatenar" que ficou com o 'R'